# Solving Trigonometric Problems Like These

Tags: trigonometry

I am not sure how to approach this problem at all. I have no idea where to start or what it wants from me.

> Find the exact value of $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ given that $\cos \theta=-\frac{3}{7}$ and that $180^\circ < \theta < 360^\circ$.

Can someone please show me what to do?[image]

Comment: Is that a typo? Or did a question just asked you with a straight face to find $\cos\theta$ given $\cos\theta$?

Comment: I edited from the original version which is just a picture, and their problem stated exactly this wording.

Comment: @Gina yes the question asked me that, the solution is going to be uploaded momentarily but I don't understand it

Answer (score 1):

Given is that $\cos(θ) = −3/7$. Conclusion based on this is that your angle is in quadrant $3$.

(Cosine is negative in quadrant 2 and 3. In this case the angle is between 180 and 360, so θ must be in quadrant 3)

Given that your angle is in quadrant $3$, draw an angle and mark $-3$ on the x-axis, $-7$ on the radius. Based on Pythagorean theorem you can now calculate the value on the y axis, namely:
$$(-7)^2=(-3)^2 + y^2.$$ so $$y^2= 49-9= 40$$ 
Therefore, $y=-2 \sqrt{10}$. Now you can figure out the other trigonometric values: $\sinθ=\frac{-2\sqrt{10}}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
1= \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = \sin^2\theta + \left( \frac{-3}{7} \right)^2 = \sin^2\theta + \frac{9}{49}
$$
So
$$
\sin^2\theta = 1-\frac{9}{49} = \frac{40}{49},\text{ so }\sin\theta = \pm\sqrt{\frac{40}{49}} = \pm\frac{2\sqrt{10}}{7}.
$$

That you need to choose minus rather than plus follows from the fact that $180^\circ\le\theta\le360^\circ$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Since you're given the interval for which $\theta$ lies, what does that tell you about the quadrant your angle lies in? Set up a right triangle and use you the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: It says > 180 but < 360. How could that help me?

Comment: Since $cos(\theta)$ is only negative in quadrants 2 and 3, we know where our angle must lie based on our interval restriction. This was explained in nice detail by deanpien.